# JsonNull after checking for jsonnull

Tags: java, json, gson

I ran into an issue a bit ago when trying to check for a isJsonNull.

Here is my code:

```
public String getGameOne() {
        if (!games.get(0).isJsonNull() || !games.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("mode").isJsonNull()) {
            return games.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("gameType").getAsString() + "\n" + "\n"
                    + games.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("mode").getAsString() + "\n"
                    + games.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("map").getAsString();
        }
        return "Returned null. (Went to housing?)";
```

I don't know if I am doing this correctly, but as you see i have an if statement checking if the game / the mode is jsonnull, however i still get JsonNull in the console and when i click it it takes me to this line:

```
games.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("mode").getAsString() + "\n"
```

I already checked for jsonnull? or at least i thought i did.

Can someone correct me or point me in the right direction? thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not mapping this onto a POJO?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this,

```
!games.get(0).isJsonNull() || !games.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("mode").isJsonNull()
```

I think it should be -

```
!games.get(0).isJsonNull() && !games.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("mode").isJsonNull()
```